# How to slice a value which is inside and obj and pass to next metod which uses it as an object

Tags: javascript

I have a specific situation where I have a method that getting an object as follow

```
async ({ locale }, ctx) => {
      const lang = await LanguageService(ctx).getLanguage({
        locale,
      });
      return lang.direction ? 'rtl' : 'ltr';
    },
```

The `{ locale }` is equal to a request as `locale: en_US`.

The next method I need to use `getLanguage` accepts `{ locale }` but I have to pass only the `en`.

So I thought to do slice but if I send it as for example

```
const sliced = locale.slice(0,2)
const lang = await LanguageService(ctx).getLanguage({
            sliced, // or locale: sliced
          });
```

From the next method the locale is showed as undefined and I have no clue how to pass only `en` in this situation I have

The method `getLanguage`

```
async getLanguage({ id, locale }) {
    console.log('locale: ', locale);
    if (!id && !locale) {
      const errorMessage = 'Specify ID or locale';
      throw new ApolloError(errorMessage);
    }

    const filter = id ? { id } : { locale };

    try {
      return await this.withDAO(({ languages }) =>
        languages.selectFirst(filter)
      );
    } catch (error) {
      throw new ApolloError(error.message);
    }
  }
```

This method needs `{ locale }` and I need to pass `en` and not `en_US`

I have no clue how to reach that as when I reach this above method the console.log(locale) is showing undefined when I use slice.

There is a way I can use that obj in the way I need

Comment: FYI, `{ sliced }` and `{ locale: sliced }` are not the same thing and might explain why you're getting `undefined`.

Comment: Yes but both giving me undefined in the second method also that an issue I tried different combination always hitting undefined

Comment: that's correct - `{ sliced }` is a shorthand for `{ sliced: sliced }`, which means the property that you're passing to the function is `sliced`, but you're trying to access `locale` (which is `undefined`).

```const lang = await LanguageService(ctx).getLanguage({
            locale: sliced });``` should work here

Comment: The problem here is that the method accepts locale so how to do so then?

Comment: I cannot pass sliced as I have to pass locale as `en` this my main issue

Comment: it's just the matter of how you're going to structure the parameter - i can't see an issue here.
Maybe the locale is not getting properly passed earlier?
I'd check what's the value of your `sliced` - other than that the code looks correct.

Comment: The locale getting en_US soon as I sliced to have en on the next method is crashing saying undefined because is expecting { locale } so my question is how can I sliced the original locale and then pass again as a locale?

Comment: When I get into the end of the getLanguage method I have this in console.log(filter) -> filter:  { locale: 'en_US' } and I have to pass as { locale: 'en'} is that possible somehow?

Comment: i would advise to just go through your code piece by piece again - you must be doing something wrong, referring to a wrong variable, passing a wrong object to the function

Comment: Finally found thank you for the suggestions and help I missed one thing and that cause the issue finally all works yeah :)